# PrincipalContext and error Value was invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, principal, userprincipal

I have a WCF service with the code:

```
var ctx = new PrincipalContext(IsLocalMachine(strDomain) ? ContextType.Machine : ContextType.Domain);
Principal principal = Principal.FindByIdentity(ctx, name)
```

I have 3 different test environments:

1: IIS 8.5  .NET v4.5 application pool, Win 8.1,  `strDomain = "testdomen1"
name = "testdomen1\testuser"` - the environment does not have errors.

2: IIS 7.5  .NET v4.5 application pool, Win Server 2008 r2, `strDomain = "testdomen1", name = "testdomen1\testuser"` - - the environment does not have errors.

3: IIS 8.5  .NET v4.5 application pool, Win 8,  `strDomain = "testdomen2"
name = "testdomen2\testuser2"` - the environment  has errors.
on the line

```
Principal principal = Principal.FindByIdentity(ctx, name)
argument exception
Value was invalid.
Parameter name: sddlForm

StackTrace
   at System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier..ctor(String sddlForm)
```

If I use Debug>BreakPoint for this line and "Add Watch" or "Quick Watch",  I get a result. But after pressing F10, I got the error.

What could be the reason?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".